# Unable to boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu. Unable to reinstall GRUB

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu

I installed Ubuntu along with Windows 10. I am able to boot Ubuntu after that, but unable to boot up Windows. 
I am new to Linux. When I reboot the laptop, the only picture I see is:

[image]

I performed a boot repair, but check box "Repair Windows boot files" is grayed out.

I tried to reinstall the GRUB by using this command:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

But got message showing:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: error: cannot open directory ' /boot/grub/i386-pc':  no such file or directory
```

[image]

What are my options? I really need my Windows back. 
I have dell laptop and tried Windows recovery, by pushing F8 multiple times, but was not able to enter recovery menu. 
Please help...

Comment: Is Windows 10 an original install from vendor as UEFI, or an upgrade from Windows 7 which probably is BIOS. You need to have Ubuntu installed in same boot mode as Windows. And the boot mode you select to boot flash drive installer is the mode it uses to install, but that may not be default boot mode of system. IF UEFI, you can still boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12(check manual). Post link to report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info  What model Dell? https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en

Comment: The image in your post indicates to me that you are booting from installation media. Have you tried removing the installation disk/flash drive prior to rebooting?

Comment: I tried that as well. All I see its `grub rescue>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your problem description there is possibility that unknowingly you have removed windows boot loader, few times (exceptionally) grub loader does not work to boot windows os. So now what you can do is you can insert the Windows 10 usb disk and try to repair. If this work for you then great if not then you might format your windows 10 installed partition.

I had same problem and this solution worked for me.